# AADJ Autopilot Win 10/11 devices unable to "see" domain in locations when attempting to add via local users and groups

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain, azure, intune

When attempting to browse the domain to add a domain user or group I'm only able to see local machine objects, on all computers.

I'm curious what setting causes this. It seems to be on all machines so I'm assuming it's a setting in Intune, but I'm unable to identify what specifically is responsible for this. Is there something in Intune/Autopilot that achieves this or is something else going on here?

Comment: IIRC (almost) all “classic” permission GUIs cannot deal with Azure AD.

Comment: Interesting. I dont see this documented anywhere. Do you have a source?

Comment: No. I just know from personal experience that you cannot add Azure AD users to ACLs and the like because they all use the same outdated “Select User or Group” dialog. Only CLI tools _just do it_.

Comment: Well thanks. It's odd answers to this arent more easily found.